# New Http Session obtained in PreProcessInterceptor on every Request

Tags: java, resteasy

I have an interceptor that implements **PreProcessInterceptor**.

I need to get the **HttpSession** object in the **preProcess** method, so I'm using:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

and then:

```
 httpRequest.getSession();
```

to get the **HttpSession** object.

At first I thought everything was working fine, but then I realized that the **httpRequest.getSession()** was returning a new HttpSession object on every request.

I need to set some session attributes on the user first request and then use those attributes on futher requests. The attributes are being set all right, I can even access those attributes down along that same request stack. However, as I am getting a new Session on every new request, I am not able to access those attributes.

Do I need to send something from the client side do my REST services, like a token or something?

Here is a more complete view of my Interceptor

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@SecurityPrecedence
public class SecurityInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor, AcceptedByMethod {
    ...
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Class classe, Method metodo) {
        return metodo.getAnnotation(PermitAll.class) == null;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod resourceMethod) {

        HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession();
        // Set attributes on httpSession
        ...

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session is tried to the concept of HTTP Cookies.

The processing of the First HTTP request would have detected that there is no current Session and created a new one. The Session ID would've then been populated as a Cookie (Http Response Header) whenever the Response was returned to the Client.

If your Second HTTP Request had a Request Header for that same Cookie, then httpSession wouldn't be created new.

So, whenever you are sending requests to the Server, check if there exists a Cookie in the Server and send that cookie with each request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I believe you are right, but I'm having troubles validating your answer, because I've bumped in another problem: jQuery is not processing the cookies because I'm using CORS, I'm trying to solve that and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Nice, using cookies solved my initial problem. Now I have to figure out how to allow cookies and use CORS at the same time... I'm building a REST API to be used by a mobile app btw.

Comment: There is no necessity for "Session". You can always create your ID (some random generated UUID), and return it to the Browser.  Store the ID in a javascript variable at "window" or "document" level.  And then make all subsequent requests send the same ID back to the browser.  Create a relational table or some in-memory "static" hashmap, which will store ID ==> Values mapping.